# different gcc versions giving different outputs

Tags: c, gcc

The below code adds new domain name and ip address to a table or modifies the value of the old entires.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>



struct DNS {
    char server_name[50];
    char ip[20];
};

struct DNS table[20];

int validate_ip(char* ip){
    int valid_ip = 1;
    int already_exists = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in address;

    if (inet_pton (AF_INET, ip, &address.sin_addr) == 0) {
        printf ("Invalid IP address. Please re-enter the correct IP address.\n");
        valid_ip = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if(strcmp (ip, table[i].ip) == 0){
            printf ("IP address already exists.\n");
            already_exists = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (valid_ip && !already_exists);
    

}

void printDnsTable(int count){

    printf("\n\n\t\tSERVER NAME\t   IP ADDRESS\n");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("\t\t%-19s%-s\n", table[i].server_name, table[i].ip);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int count = 0;
    char choice;
    
    char domain_name[50];
    char ip_address[50];
    int i;

    do {

        printf("count:%d\n",count);
        if(count == 0) {
            printf("DNS cache empty.\n");
            printf("Do you want to add/modify the DNS table(y/n)?");
            scanf("%s", &choice);
            if(choice == 'n') {
                break;
            }
        }
                  
        printf("Domain name: ");
        scanf("%s",domain_name);
        for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
            if(strcmp(domain_name,table[i].server_name) == 0 ){
                break; 
            }
        }
        
ip:     strcpy(ip_address, " ");
        printf("IP address: ");
        scanf("%s", ip_address);
        if(validate_ip(ip_address) == 0){
            goto ip;
        }
        if(i == 20){
            strcpy(table[count].server_name,domain_name);
            strcpy(table[count].ip,ip_address);
        } else {
            strcpy(table[i].ip,ip_address);
        }

        **count+=1;**

        printDnsTable(count);
        

        choice = ' ';
        printf("\nDo you want to add/modify the DNS table?(y/n)");
        scanf("%s", &choice);


    } while(choice == 'y');


}
```

The count variable in the do-while loop gets the value as 0 in each iteration even though I have incremented it.This is the output that I got for the above code with gcc 9.3

> count:0 
> DNS cache empty.
>  Do you want to add/modify the DNS table(y/n)?y 
> Domain name: yahoo.com 
> IP address: 10.2.45.67
>
> ```
>   SERVER NAME    IP ADDRESS   
>   yahoo.com      10.2.45.67
> ```
>
> Do you want to add/modify the DNS table?(y/n)y 
> count:0 
> DNS cache empty. 
> Do you want to add/modify the DNS table(y/n)?n

The same code gave me the correct output when I used an online compiler that uses gcc 5.4.1.
Why is there a discrepancy? Have I gone wrong somewhere? I'm not able to downgrade my gcc version, so how can I make this code work with gcc 9.3?

Comment: `scanf("%s", &choice);` -> UB. Your `choice` is a single `char` and not a string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sometimes, %c consumes a newline from the input buffer and skips getting an input. I've tried fflush() but it doesn't work all the time for me. So, this is a workaround solution that I've devised. But, I've tried %c and it has no effect on the count variable here.

Comment: @Mia try `" %c"`, mind the space before `%`, it discards blank characters present on `stdin` including `\n`.

Comment: Better yet, don't use `scanf`.  If you're going to use `scanf`, you must limit `%s` to the size of the buffer (eg `%10s` if your buffer can hold at least 11 bytes) and you *must* check the value returned.  Any time you call scanf and don't check the return value, it is a bug.

Comment: This "workaround" is a definite bug as it will overflow the buffer *in any case*. It will read a character and append `\0` next to it. `fflush(stdin)` is UB in most cases too. Use the method @anastaciu proposed

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",domain_name);`  It should be: `if( scanf("%49s",domain_name) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for domain_name failed\n" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  like: 20, 50.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: regarding; `ip:     strcpy(ip_address, " ");
        printf("IP address: ");
        scanf("%s", ip_address);
        if(validate_ip(ip_address) == 0){
            goto ip;`  this is a great way to generate spaghetti code.  Suggest: `do { 
        printf( "IP address: " );
        if( scanf("%49s", ip_address) != 1 ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for address failed\n" );  break;
        } while( ! validate_ip( ip_address ) );

Comment: regarding; `char domain_name[50];` and `char ip_address[50];`  Strongly suggest replacing with: `char domain_name[50] = {0};` and `char ip_address[50]  = {0};` so those arrays are initialized with all NUL values

Comment: regarding: `if(choice == 'n')` What if the user entered `N`?  What if all the user entered is `'\n'?`

Comment: regarding; `for(i=0; i<20; i++) 
        {
            if(strcmp(domain_name,table[i].server_name) == 0 )
            {
                break; 
            }
        }`  this is comparing (up to) 20 table entries that have not been initialized.  The result is undefined behavior.  Suggest: `for(i=0; i<count; i++)`

Comment: regarding; `if(i == 20)
        { // then no matching entry found
            strcpy(table[count].server_name,domain_name);
            strcpy(table[count].ip,ip_address);
        }`  after correcting the loop that sets `i` this code block should start with: `if(i == count )`

Comment: regarding: `while(choice == 'y');`  What if the user entered `Y`?  Never trust the user to do what your code is expecting, always verify user input

Comment: regarding: `if(count == 0) 
        {
            printf("DNS cache empty.\n");
            printf("Do you want to add/modify the DNS table(y/n)?");
            scanf(" %c", &choice);
            if(choice == 'n') 
            {
                break;
            }
        }`   suggest removing the outer `if()` statement `if(count == 0) ` otherwise, once a single entry is in the table (and `count` has been incremented) this check will be skipped.  Then the program will not know when to stop